# Is the F1 Score sensitive to the threshold?

Tags: model-evaluations, score

Is the F1 score sensitive or indifferent to the threshold (for defining positive or negative)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is. The formula:

$$F_1 = \frac{2TP}{2TP + FP + FN}$$

There is no symmetry. You have only $TP$ in the nominator which means that $F_1=0$ if $threshold=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is.

For an evaluation measure independent from the threshold, look at the [Area Under the Curve (AUC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve).